# SP with Encryption Read/Writes Stats

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, index-statistics

If a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 is created with the syntax "WITH ENCRYPTION" ,are the reads and writes of the encrypted stored procedure recorded in the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats? I am calculating reads by using the user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups columns and the writes by using the  user_updates column of this DMV. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: Encryption hides the SQL text of the SP when running just wanted to make sure it was not hiding anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it out myself and yes the stats are counted from an encrypted stored procedure if anyone else is looking for the answer.